# How to run only the first conditional OR in WHERE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query and I would like to get only those rows who satisfies the **first** `OR` condition. I want to check conditions such as if the first `OR` will not have satisfy condition, then I should see the second `OR` and etc.

This is a simple example. However, these are really big tables with 30 millions of row. I cannot use full join. And my code should be put into function.

My sample data:

```
DECLARE @tbl_1 TABLE (Id INT)

DECLARE @tbl_2 TABLE (Id INT)

DECLARE @tbl_3 TABLE (Id INT)

DECLARE @tbl_4 TABLE (Id INT)
```

and its data:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_1 ([Id]) VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)

INSERT INTO @tbl_2 ([Id]) VALUES (8)

INSERT INTO @tbl_3 ([Id]) VALUES (3)

INSERT INTO @tbl_4 ([Id]) VALUES (4)

SELECT  * FROM @tbl_1 AS t
WHERE t.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tbl_2 AS t2)
    OR t.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tbl_3 AS t2)
    OR t.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tbl_4 AS t2)
```

Then I would like to see just one item:

```
3
```

But it gives:  `3, 4`

Or another example:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_1 ([Id]) VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)

INSERT INTO @tbl_2 ([Id]) VALUES (1), (2) 

INSERT INTO @tbl_3 ([Id]) VALUES (3)

INSERT INTO @tbl_4 ([Id]) VALUES (4)

SELECT  * FROM @tbl_1 AS t
WHERE t.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tbl_2 AS t2)
    OR t.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tbl_3 AS t2)
    OR t.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tbl_4 AS t2)
```

Then I would like to see just two first items:

```
1, 2
```

But it gives:  `1, 2, 3, 4`

I've tried to use `OR`. However, it takes all items which satisfy condition.
How is it possible to write `WHERE` statement where just one **first** `OR` statement will be executed?

Comment: If you only want the first `OR` clause to be used, why are the other 2 there..? If you don't want them there, remove them.

Comment: @Larnu I want to check other tables such as if the first `OR` will not have satisfy condition, then I should see the second `OR` and etc.

Comment: SQL `OR` clauses aren't like a `CASE` expression or `Switch` statement, where when the first boolean expression returns `true` the rest of the values are ignored. Also, it works on the row, so the fact that a result returned `true` for id `3` previously means nothing for id `4`. This feels like an odd requirement, if I am honest, and possibly an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: (1) How many records in each table? (2) how many records are you expecting to get as a result for your question? (3) is there any overlap between table 2,3 & 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a ranking. Rows from @tbl_2 have precedence over rows from table @tbl_3 and these again have precedence over rows from table @tbl_4.

Ideally you would just have one table instead of three and store the priority along:

```
INSERT INTO @ids (id, priority) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3);
```

As we are looking for the best overall priority (in contrast to, say, looking for the best match per product or the like), we can join, order our rows by priority and use `TOP WITH TIES` to only keep the rows with the best priority.

```
SELECT  TOP(1) WITH TIES t.* 
FROM @tbl_1 AS t
JOIN @ids ids ON ids.id = t.id
ORDER BY ids.priority;
```

If you want to stick with the three tabes, then add the priority on-the-fly:

```
WITH ids AS
(
  SELECT id, 1 AS priority FROM @tbl_2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 2 AS priority FROM @tbl_3
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 3 AS priority FROM @tbl_4
)
SELECT  TOP(1) WITH TIES t.* 
FROM @tbl_1 AS t
JOIN ids ON ids.id = t.id
ORDER BY ids.priority;
```

Comment: thanks for the your reply. However, my real tables are really big tables with 30 millions of row. Is it possible to write query without cte?

Comment: Well, the first query doesn't have a CTE. The second one has a CTE, but that CTE has a very small result set (namely the IDs you are looking for). And why do you think that a CTE decreases performance? It doesn't. Both queries should run rather fast.

Comment: What happens, though, is that we join all IDs first and then group and rank and dismiss rows again. I suppose you'd rather want some condition, like join tbl_2 first, and if there was no match join tbl_3, and if there was again no match join tbl_4. But although this sounds more effective, it probably wouldn't be (and it wouldn't be easy to write in SQL anyway.)

Comment: Same here. No need for RANK

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz: Ah, you are right. As there is no partitioning, we don't need `RANK`, but can simply `ORDER BY ids.priority`. I've overcomplicated this a little. `RANK` is only necessary when we have groups, like looking for the best rows per product or the like. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_1 AS t
WHERE
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t.id)
AND
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_1 t1
 JOIN tbl_2 t2
 ON t2.id = t1.id) > 0
OR (
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_3 t3 WHERE t3.id = t.id)
    AND
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_1 t1
     JOIN tbl_2 t2
     ON t2.id = t1.id) = 0
    AND
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_1 t1
     JOIN tbl_3 t3
     ON t3.id = t1.id) > 0
)
OR (
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_4 t4 WHERE t4.id = t.id)
AND
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_1 t1
 JOIN tbl_2 t2
 ON t2.id = t1.id) = 0
AND
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_1 t1
 JOIN tbl_3 t3
 ON t3.id = t1.id) = 0
AND
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_1 t1
 JOIN tbl_4 t4
 ON t4.id = t1.id) > 0
)
```

In this way you have the OR exclusive

[Sql Fiddle #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4509c/13/0) (with dataset 1, 2; 3; 4)

[Sql Fiddle #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eb864/2/0) (with dataset 8; 3; 4)

Comment: This returns both `3` and `4` for the OP's first set up data.

Comment: @Larnu I've fixed my query

Answer (score 1):

Assuming t2, t3 & t4 have unique values.
You would probably would like to verify that the execution plan is based on merge joins / hash joins and not nested loops.

```
select  top 1 with ties
        t1.*
        
from              @tbl_1 AS t1
        left join @tbl_2 as t2 on t2.id = t1.id
        left join @tbl_3 as t3 on t3.id = t1.id
        left join @tbl_4 as t4 on t4.id = t1.id
        
where   coalesce(t2.id,t3.id,t4.id) is not null

order by case 
             when t2.Id is not null then 1
             when t3.Id is not null then 2
             when t4.Id is not null then 3
         end
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ffb2f2f11731c38f68727c3b8f5478f7)

Another solution with no JOINs at all. Only GROUP BY :-)

```
select      top 1 with ties

            id
        
from        (         select id, 999 from @tbl_1
            union all select id, 1   from @tbl_2
            union all select id, 2   from @tbl_3
            union all select id, 3   from @tbl_4
            ) t (id,priority)
        
group by    id 

having      max(priority) = 999

order by    min(priority)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac2111d059149e963265667a2c8905e3)

Comment: thanks for the your reply. However, my real tables are really big tables with 30 millions of row. Is it possible to write query without cte?

Comment: You have some wrong assumption regarding CTE / queries execution.
The database does not execute it the way you wrote it.
`select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from t) as t) as t) as t) as t) ` does not go over the data 5 times, only once.

Comment: @Learner - it helps to realise/remember that in SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. The CTE is just a way of representing what's wanted, not a separate step that has to be processed fully before the main query is - it's all optimised together.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: See updated answer (again :-)). @LukStorms had a nice syntax tweak using TOP 1 WITH TIES but he missed the fact that with this syntax there isn't really any need for RANK / DENSE_RANK

Comment: ... and another one :-) A follow-up on @Thorsten Kettner suggested solution

Answer (score 1):

A `TOP (1) WITH TIES` with an `ORDER BY` over a `CASE WHEN` for the 3 table id's would do the job.

If nothing matched with `@tbl_2` then the matches of `@tbl_3` will come on top.  And if no match with `@tbl_2` & `@tbl_3` then `@tbl_4` will come on top.

> ```
> DECLARE @tbl_1 TABLE (Id INT)
> DECLARE @tbl_2 TABLE (Id INT)
> DECLARE @tbl_3 TABLE (Id INT)
> DECLARE @tbl_4 TABLE (Id INT)
> INSERT INTO @tbl_1 ([Id]) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)
> INSERT INTO @tbl_2 ([Id]) VALUES (8)
> INSERT INTO @tbl_3 ([Id]) VALUES (3)
> INSERT INTO @tbl_4 ([Id]) VALUES (4)
>
> SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
> FROM @tbl_1 AS t
> LEFT JOIN @tbl_2 t2 ON t2.Id = t.Id
> LEFT JOIN @tbl_3 t3 ON t3.Id = t.Id
> LEFT JOIN @tbl_4 t4 ON t4.Id = t.Id
> WHERE t.Id IN (t2.Id, t3.Id, t4.Id)
> ORDER BY CASE 
>          WHEN t2.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
>          WHEN t3.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 3
>          WHEN t4.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 4
>          END;
> ```

> | Id |
> | --- |
> | 3 |

> ```
> DECLARE @tbl_1 TABLE (Id INT)
> DECLARE @tbl_2 TABLE (Id INT)
> DECLARE @tbl_3 TABLE (Id INT)
> DECLARE @tbl_4 TABLE (Id INT)
> INSERT INTO @tbl_1 ([Id]) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)
> INSERT INTO @tbl_2 ([Id]) VALUES (1), (2) 
> INSERT INTO @tbl_3 ([Id]) VALUES (3)
> INSERT INTO @tbl_4 ([Id]) VALUES (4)
>
> SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES t.*
> FROM @tbl_1 AS t
> LEFT JOIN @tbl_2 t2 ON t2.Id = t.Id
> LEFT JOIN @tbl_3 t3 ON t3.Id = t.Id
> LEFT JOIN @tbl_4 t4 ON t4.Id = t.Id
> WHERE t.Id IN (t2.Id, t3.Id, t4.Id)
> ORDER BY CASE 
>          WHEN t2.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 2
>          WHEN t3.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 3
>          WHEN t4.Id IS NOT NULL THEN 4
>          END;
> ```

> | Id |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=c7c95c19618ea459bf4cd9b5aaa5a9f2)*

Comment: No need for RANK / DENSE_RANK

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz You're right! Thanks, it'll be faster without it. I hadn't considered it because often you'd wrap it a sub-query, then filter on it.

Answer (score 0):

One other idea you might entertain, although not exactly elegant, is a more procedural approach so you only end up touching a table if you need to which will be more performant if that's a concern.

Insert qualifying IDs into a temp table and only move on if there are no results at each stage, for example

```
create table #results (id int);

insert into #results 
select id
from t1 where exists (select * from t2 where t2.id=t1.id)

if @@RowCount=0
begin
    insert into #results 
    select id
    from t1 where exists (select * from t3 where t3.Id=t1.Id)

    if @@RowCount=0
    begin
        insert into #results 
        select id
        from t1 where exists (select * from t4 where t4.Id=t1.Id)
    end
end

select id
from #results
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3e9bcb7c6aa7c870342193780b1d5e4)